# you cannot call a method on a null-valued expressions

Tags: null, expression

I am trying to replace some texts in a text file using the existing values. The values I am getting from azure table and stored to variable `$entries`.

```
Foreach($entry in $entries){

(Get-content) $filepath | 

for-eachobject 
{ 

$_ -replace"@Name",$entry.Name.trim()

-replace"@Class",$entry.classname.trim()

-replace "@Address",$entry.address.trim()

-replace "@Mobile",$entry.phonenumber.trim()

} | Set-content $filepath

}
```

Comment: One more problem is --> when $data = $entry  then $data contains values of one row. But $Name = $entry.Name.trim() here $Name contains empty